# Show Full URL in HTTP Text

Tags: html, http

[Image of How it Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn6nC.jpg)i am using Blab Chat Script , in chat, when i write some URL for example http://example.com/examplepage/example.html and enter. it only shows this "example.com/examplepage/..."

it only shows 25 Characters of URL, how can i remove this limit and shows full URL.

there is a funtion in blab.js that might effect this

```
function convjs(x){
y=/\%/g; x=x.replace(y,'%25');
y=/&/g;  x=x.replace(y,'%26');
y=/\+/g; x=x.replace(y,'%2B');
return x;}
```

i want it like this
    www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

Comment: Use a link shortener?

Comment: @JohannesJander actually i want to see what is the url without clicking on it, means when someone post http://example.com/example/example so it shows full url in text so i know what is this.